# Codeigniter image upload will only upload to one dir

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

```
function upload($path){
  $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
  $config['max_size'] = 2000;

  if($path =='profile'){
   $config['upload_path'] = '../assets/uploads/avatars';
   $config['file_name'] = $this->id;  
  }
  if($path =='company'){
   $config['upload_path'] = '../assets/uploads/company';
   $config['file_name'] = $this->id.'_company';
  }

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  $this->upload->do_upload();

  $image_data = $this->upload->data();
  if($path == 'profile'){
   $this->db->update('be_user_profiles',array('avatar' => $image_data['file_name']), array('user_id' => $this->id));
  }
  if($path == 'company'){
   $this->db->update('be_user_profiles',array('company_logo' => $image_data['file_name']), array('user_id' => $this->id));
  }
  $config = array(
   'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
   'new_image' => $this->upload_path,
   'maintain_ratio' => true,
   'width' => 500,
   'height' => 500
  );

  $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
  $this->image_lib->resize();
 }
```

This is my upload function, and it works fine when `$path = 'profile'`, but when it is `company`, it won't upload to the "company" folder...
Is there any reason it should be so?!  I'm at a loss here...This function works when it goes to the avatar folder, but not if it goes to the company folder...

Comment: replace  $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); by  $this->load->library('image_lib'); $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar problem with multiple folders. The way I fixed was to use to use the initialize function instead of passing the config as an argument to the load library function.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

You could load the library then set your config and call the initialize method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't even know what the problem was...but I used this for the path: `realpath(APPPATH . '../assets/uploads/company');`...

Comment: ifaour made some very good suggestions. I would make sure you try what he says. The CI docs have the path setup this way:  './uploads' where the dot denotes from the root of the site. So the assuming your site is at http://www.mysite.com the uploads directory would be at http://www.mysiste.com/uploads.

Answer (score 2):

I think all suggestions are really good, you can also make sure you are posting the right data in your form:
 $this->upload->do_upload();  is by default expecting the form name to be 'userfile'

also I find sometimes really usefull to have some errors displayed...so instead of just  `$this->upload->do_upload();`  try something like

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($userfile)) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_error', $error);
        }
```

and then add a file in your views called upload_error.php with the following code in it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>



</body>
</html>
```

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try to unset config before setting another config like this.
The following code unset config and clear image library.

You need to clear your lib.

```
//Unset config for the next one
  unset($config);
  $this->image_lib->clear();
```

From CI manual...

[$this->image_lib->clear()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html)

The clear function resets all of the values used when processing an image. You will want to call this if you are processing images in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, Here are two suggestions:

1. Make sure your `company` folder is writable
2. What `$this->id` returns? if it's returning the file name WITH the extension then this is what causing your upload process to fail because then you'll have a file name `my_image.png_company` which is not an allowed type.
   Please refer to the [documentation page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) for more info.

Comment: `$this->id` is simply the user's id.  The upload class automagically adds the extension after the file is named.

Comment: are you sure about that? what version of CI you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config = array(
    'upload_path'   './assets/upload/profilepic/',
    'allowed_types' => 'JPG|JPEG|PNG',
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'file_name'  => date('YmdHis').''.rand(0,9999)
);
```

its not works for JPEG file type 
also i had written in small latter but it didn't works.
please Share if you have something 
JPEG files are not upload Others file are inserted easely.